# reusable web services code for iPhone

Tags: iphone, web-services, soap, code-reuse, reusability

I am very new to iPhone development and previously was working with Java.

Currently I am using SOAP web services in my project and want to continue with the same.

But everytime i have to write the same code for all kinds of web services except for the parameters.

Can anyone guide me regarding how can i create a reusable code for web-services, so that i can use it as a static library or something for every project and then i wont need to write any code separately for each kind of web service?

I want to create a code which would be very generic and will be work for all kinds of web services irrespective of the number of parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create the singleton class and method will be class methods then they will be globally used you can use them by doing a little modification in the code .

Comment: @Subashini: I a using stubs. So it takes care of everything. Like handling the response and errors etc

Comment: yes but checks will be there like if response is coming different on each method like - one is returning bool and one is array so you have to take care of all this in the response code of the web methods.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a seperate Webservices Manager Class (.h and.m) files where you have to write code for nsurlconnection and urlrequest creation in a method.
- Also place all the NSURLConnection delegate methods(connection:didRecieveResponse: etc) in the same class to handle the response coming from server.
- Create protocol methods to pass this nsdata response from the NSURLConnection delegate method(connection:didReceiveResponse:) to the appropriate classes. Implement the delegate method in those classes, get the response from this common nsurlconnection class.
- Parse the response data.

So when you need to call a webservice, just make a call to the nsurlConnection creation method of the WebservicesManager class ( [webserviceManager connectTo:@""]) to actually initiate a webservice call.